# place toolbar below status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-statusbar

[image]

how can i put the toolbar below status bar ?? i tried this on my fragmentActivty's parent layout `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` but its placing the toolbar below status bar when am  taping on my searhcView  i want it to place the toolbar below status bar when the activity loads

here my toolbar is below the status bar (status bar and icons have same color,  i'll fix it later )

[image]

i can't  use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on my mainActivity cause its causing unexpected behaviours on my other fragments

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a `marginTop` to the toolbar which is equal to the height of your statusbar.

**The Problem with that is**
Status bar height differs from screen densities. So the marginTop can't be statically provided in your xml layout

**The Solution to this problem is**
You can calculate the height of the status bar in your java code and add a marginTop in your Java code.

```
int marginTopValue = Math.ceil(25 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

As the height of the statusbar is 25px, you can calculate the its height in dp with this code.

Hope this works